# WPF GlyphRun vs TextBox

Tags: wpf

I have optimized rendering in my WPF application using GlyphRuns.

The problem is, that GlyphRuns and TextBox have different rendering result!

Example:

```
<Glyphs
     FontUri             = "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\TIMES.TTF"
     FontRenderingEmSize = "20"
     UnicodeString       = "fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
     Fill                = "Black"
     OriginX             = "5"
     OriginY             = "21"
  />
    <TextBox Background="Transparent" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="20">fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</TextBox>
```

You get this:

[image]

Any solution/idea how to get the same rendered text from both controls?

Comment: I cannot truly understand your question or example. It looks like the outputs from both controls are at one line.